# Failing to distribute fungible tokens with a virtual account

Tags: substrate-node-template, assets

We are unable to get the asset-pallet to mint according to shareInfo that is being passed along from contributions and is passed along as percentage calculation. The `from` is a virtual account, that get's generated by unique-id.

The creation of the tokens are working, we can see back in the chain state `AssetDetails` that the amount of tokens (100) are minted

When it comes to distribution of the tokens, we don't see back the balances of the users that have a share. In our tests with 2 users it works and we can see the balance of the fungible assets back.

Below we there are two snippets of code, that show the calculation of the shares and then the distribution.

**We collecting at first the contributors and their share percentage in an asset**

```rust
///Collect contributors to the bid, and their shares
pub fn owner_and_shares(collection_id: T::NftCollectionId, item_id: T::NftItemId) -> Vec<(T::AccountId, Percent)>{

//Get owners and their reserved contribution to the bid
    
    let reservation_infos = HousingFund::Reservations::<T>::get((collection_id.clone(),item_id.clone())).unwrap();
    let vec0 = reservation_infos.contributions;
    let price = reservation_infos.amount;
    let mut vec = Vec::new() ;
    for i in vec0.iter(){
        let price0 = Self::balance_to_u64_option(price).unwrap();
        let contribution = Self::balance_to_u64_option(i.1.clone()).unwrap();
        let share = Percent::from_rational(contribution,price0);
        debug_assert!(!share.is_zero()); 
        vec.push((i.0.clone(),share));
        //Update Virtual_account storage
        Virtual::<T>::mutate(collection_id.clone(),item_id.clone(),|val|{
            let mut val0 = val.clone().unwrap();
            val0.owners.push(i.0.clone());
            *val = Some(val0);
        }); 
    }
    vec
}
```

**Distribute the ownership tokens to the group of new owners**

```rust
    pub fn distribute_tokens(
        account: T::AccountId,
        collection_id: T::NftCollectionId,
        item_id: T::NftItemId,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        let shares = Self::owner_and_shares(collection_id.clone(), item_id.clone());
        ensure!(Virtual::<T>::get(collection_id, item_id).is_some(), Error::<T>::InvalidValue);
        let token_id = Virtual::<T>::get(collection_id, item_id).unwrap().token_id;
        let total_tokens = Assets::Pallet::<T>::total_supply(token_id.into());
        debug_assert!(total_tokens == Self::u32_to_balance_option(100).unwrap());

        let from = T::Lookup::unlookup(account.clone());
        let origin: OriginFor<T> = RawOrigin::Signed(account.clone()).into();

        for share in shares.iter() {
            let amount: <T as Assets::Config>::Balance = share.clone().1 * total_tokens.clone();
            debug_assert!(!amount.clone().is_zero());
            let to = T::Lookup::unlookup(share.clone().0);
            Assets::Pallet::<T>::force_transfer(
                origin.clone(),
                token_id.clone().into(),
                from.clone(),
                to,
                amount,
            )
            .ok();
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```